# perl remove inexistence path from text file

Tags: file, perl

I would like to read the path from a text file, and check if the path existing. If the path exists, remain the entry in the file, else removed from the same file. Below code is buggy where some of the existing entry got removed as well

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file="/path/to/file.txt";
my @new_line_list;
open(FH1, "<", $file ) or die "Can't open file for reading: $!"; 
while(my $line = <FH1>){
   chomp $line;
    next if (!-d $line);
    @new_line_list=$line;
}
close( FH1 ); 
        
# Rewrite file with the line removed
open(FH2, ">", $file ) or die "Can't open file for reading: $!"; 
   foreach my $line ( @new_line_list) { 
       print FH2 $line; 
   } 
    close(FH2);
```

Comment: `perl -ni -e'print if -d' /path/to/file.txt` should do the trick as well.

Comment: @TLP: You might need a `-l` to remove newlines.

Comment: @choroba That's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@new_line_list=$line;
```

You're overwriting the list of lines every time. Instead, use [push](http://p3rl.org/push):

```
push @new_line_list, $line;
```

Another option would be to write to a different file and [rename](http://p3rl.org/rename) it over the original file when done.